# Text of posts is suddenly not visible anymore

Tags: troubleshooting

(WordPress 3.8 running Twenty Eleven theme.)

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/

I just realized that neither on the Wordpress homepage nor after opening a post I can see any text.

If I click on edit though or choose a post from the manager then everything seems alright. Everything is in place, including the title of the posts. Just the text of a post is not visible on the blog.

If I remember correctly this issue is no direct result of the latest Wordpress update.

I don't even have an idea right now where to look for the reason.

Comment: I'd recommend disabling some plugins first, and going from there. It could very well be your `wp-flattr-button` that's causing the issue.

Comment: Setting WP_DEBUG to TRUE in your WP-CONFIG.php file might show you some thing?

Comment: thanks both of you! @DylanHildenbrand: your guess was almost right - it was the "ShareThis" plugin. You're welcome to turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend disabling some plugins first, and going from there. It could very well be your `wp-flattr-button` that's causing the issue.

In the case, it seemed to be the ShareThis plugin.

Comment: Had same issue (body text of posts not showing) and disabling all plug-ins solved it.